# Python-Pickle Str-Int conversion

Tags: python, pickle

So I'm doing this task assignment thing to improve my knowledge of how to pickle in python. Long story short the task is to create a maths quiz, save the data to an external folder then unpickle the data and sort it(Alphabetically, averages, Highest to lowest etc.) The problem I'm is in order for the score to be saved it has to pickled as a string, rather than integer `strscore = str(score)`
How do I convert the score back to an integer once it's been pickled, I've tried `scores = pickle.load(datafile)` `intscore = int(scores)` but i get returned with the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` Please help, all i need is for the score value to be returned as an integer so i can add up the full scores, Thanks

#### EDIT

```
scorestr = str(score)
newscore = ""
if score < 10:
    newscore = "0"+(scorestr)
else:
    newscore = "010"
```

This is the part of the program where the score from the quiz is saved

Comment: It is really necessary convert it to string before serialize to disk?

May you describe better your code using some snippets of it?

May you debug or print(type(scores)) and check its type?

Comment: why are you calling str on the score?

Comment: Using print(type(scores)) returns class 'str' How can i change this?

Comment: I'm using str(score) so i can add "0" onto it to allow me to sort it later on in the program, so it would go from 0,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,010

Comment: To help us to test it and try to help better, may you edit your post with a snippet of your code? Maybe there a simple solution to format yours numbers and turn sort easier.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you do this to load the file:

```
scores = pickle.load(datefile)
print(type(scores))
intscore = int(scores)
```

If `print(type(scores))` returns class 'str', it indicates that when you load the datefile, it already returns a string, so the problem is probable in `pickle.dump()`.

Can you please give us the part of your code in which you do `pickle.dump()`?